# Can't achieve smooth handle animation when assigning slider value programatically - jQuery UISlider

Tags: jquery, uislider

I am using the jQuery UISlider.  I have it set up so that upon the execution of the event "slidestop" (ie when the user stops sliding), some code will determine if it is higher or lower than a given value in the range of the slider.  The code then determines which of a given set of values the slider is closest to, and then attempts to move the slider handle to that point.  All that is essentially working fine.  here's my dilema:

The handle does not animate to the new location, rather is jumps there.  I am using this line of code to move the handle:

```
$("#navScroller").slider('value', newScrollerValue);
```

where **newScrollerValue** is the value the logic decided the handle needed to be sent to.

If I use the same line of code in a click event binded to an element on the page, (but giving it a test value for **newScrollerValue**), the handle animates to the new location as it should.  But placing it within the callback method for the **slidestop** event makes it jumps to the new location rather than animate smoothly.

I hope that explains it clearly enough.  Any thoughts on what I could do to achieve a smooth handle animation to a programatically assigned value within the **slidestop** event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation might be disabled internally during the time the handle is being dragged, see if you can perform the action in a new context after the event fires:

```
$("#navScroller").bind("slidestop", function (event, ui) {
   setTimeout(function () {
     //perform the required logic here
     $("#navScroller").slider('value', newScrollerValue);
   },10);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer.  That was exactly the problem and it works just fine now!